# Node Postgres COPY FROM failing silently

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to use PostgreSQL's `COPY FROM` API to stream potentially-thousands of records into a database as they are dynamically generated in node.js code. To do so, I wrote this generic wrapper function:

```js
function streamRows(client, { table, columns, data }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sqlStream = client.query(
      copyFrom(`COPY ${ table } (${ columns.join(', ') }) FROM STDIN`));

    const rowStream = new Readable();

    rowStream.pipe(sqlStream)
      .on('finish', resolve)
      .on('error', reject);

    for (const row of data) {
      rowStream.push(`${ row.join('\t') }\n`);
    }

    rowStream.push('\\.\n');
    rowStream.push(null);
  });
}
```

The database table I'm writing into looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE devices (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id INTEGER REFERENCES groups(id),
  serial_number CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  status INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

And I am calling it as follows:

```js
function *genRows(id, devices) {
  let count = 0;

  for (const serial of devices) {
    yield [ id, serial, UNSTARTED ];
    count++;
    if (count % 10 === 0) log.info(`Streamed ${ count } rows...`);
  }

  log.info(`Streamed ${ count } rows.`);
}

await streamRows(client, {
  table: 'devices',
  columns: [ 'group_id', 'serial_number', 'status' ],
  data: genRows(id, devices),
});
```

The log statements in my generator function that's producing the per-row data all run as expected, and the output indicates that it is in fact always running the generator to completion, and streaming all the data rows I want. No errors are ever thrown. But if I wait for it to complete, the table sometimes ends up with 0 rows added to it--i.e., it looks like I sent all that data to Postgres, but *none* of it was actually inserted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what parts of this made the difference and what is purely stylistic, but after playing around with a bunch of different examples from across the web, I managed to cobble together this function which works:

```js
function streamRows(client, { table, columns, data }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const iterator = data[Symbol.iterator]();
    const rs = new Readable();
    const ws = client.query(copyFrom(`COPY ${ table } (${ columns.join(', ') }) FROM STDIN`));

    rs._read = function() {
      const { value, done } = iterator.next();

      rs.push(done ? null : `${ value.join('\t') }\n`);
    };

    rs.on('error', reject);
    ws.on('error', reject);
    ws.on('end', resolve);
    rs.pipe(ws);
  });
}
```